# How can I get the CSS for browser (Chrome) context menu?

Tags: css, google-chrome, contextmenu

I've made a custom context menu. I'd like the styling to be as close to Chrome's context menu as possible. I'm wondering how I can find the CSS for Chrome's context menu, or for any browser for that matter.

Comment: I suggest making two context menu themes because you can actually change your context menu to a light/dark theme through the Windows Settings.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr, worthy idea. Now how to do I get Chrome's/Window's defaults?